# Does Android AudioTrack use automatic buffering?

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

When you create a new `AudioTrack` you set its buffer size. Then you `write()` audio data to the audio stream specifying its length.

In my case `getMinBufferSize()` gives me `8192 B` and my audio is `22050 B`.

So does the `AudioTrack` buffer that sound automatically or should I split my `short[]` for the audio data into chunks each equal to the buffer size?

(Or, in the last case, just changing `offsetInShorts` and `sizeInShorts` parameters of `write()` dynamically to feed corresponding portions of the sound data to the track?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that I've been just writing my entire audio into `AudioTrack` at once and haven't had any problems with it so far, I'd say yes, there's some sort of automatic buffer filling magic.

Digging deeper, the write calls of `AudioTrack` end up calling [AudioFlinger::PlaybackThread::OutputTrack::write](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/109347d421413303eb1678dd9e2aa9d40acf89d2/services/audioflinger/AudioFlinger.cpp#5498) which seems to write to the first non-filled buffer and then continue writing into new buffers if there's more data.

Answer (score 0):

If you monitor the size of the stream in a timer you can determine how big the current array is where:

```
AudioStream:= TJavaArray<smallint>.Create(trackmin);
```

And:

```
trackmin:= TJAudioTrack.JavaClass.getMinBufferSize(11025, TJAudioFormat.JavaClass.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, TJAudioFormat.JavaClass.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

var
NewCount: Integer;
begin
    aCounter:=aCounter+1;
    NewCount:= (AudioRecorder as JAudioRecord).read(AudioStream,0,AudioStr.Length);//3584
```